# Controlling mpd/ncmpcpp on laptop from iphone

Tags: ios, linux, bluetooth, mpd

I just set up ncmpcpp on the ubuntu side of my macbook pro, and I'm trying to make an iphone app to control it. How would I go about doing this?

Should I use bluetooth or wifi? (which one would be easier)
And then how would I go about implementing it? What packages should I install in linux? And how would I use them?

I know it's kind of a big topic, and I have several broad questions, but if you can answer any of them or provide any information that would help, I would be incredibly grateful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like an ambitious project with a significant scope.

Whenever ideas like this crop up, it's good to take a step back and ask: "What am I trying to accomplish?".

Are you simply wanting to run a music "server" on your Ubuntu portion, and access it via your iPhone? Or are you trying to make a "remote control"?

There are likely apps that will do what you're wanting to do... I know, I know mdp/ncmpcpp is super neat looking, but... practicality!

Comment: It's not really a matter of practicality...I'm just trying to learn how to do this sort of stuff so I can eventually design my own versions of that software somewhere down the line.  Any information as to how this sort of stuff works: either the bluetooth on either end (the ubuntu or the ios), or the connecting to mpd would be awesome!